# sub menu loads on button press aand has an editable text box ANDROID

Tags: android, eclipse, button, submenu

I am currently trying to add a sub menu and get it to do what I want. I've been looking online and can't seem to see if it's possible.

Right basically I have a button called 'sign-in' which the users will press to lad the submenu in which will have a label saying Username and then an editable text box allowing the user to type in their desired user name.

Is this possible?

The code I currently have is

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    TextView txtUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    EditText edit_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_username);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    SubMenu sub = menu.addSubMenu(0,1,0, "Sign-In");
    sub.add(0,11,0,edit_username);    //I have noticed this is wrong but the only way I thought it would work
    sub.add(0,12,0,txtUsername);    //same for here

    //add button for okaying the username

    return true;
}
```

obviously this is in the create options menu but like I said I would like it to load the menu when the user clicks sign in using the signIn void

```
public void signIn(View view) 
{
 //load menu here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any number sub menus to the menu items but you cannot nest a sub menu. ([Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SubMenu.html))

Menus with sub menus are used in rare cases where there are a number of related sub menu items for a menu item.

> You can add a submenu to an item in any menu (except a submenu) by adding a  element as the child of an . Submenus are useful when your application has a lot of functions that can be organized into topics, like items in a PC application's menu bar (File, Edit, View, etc.).

Refer [this document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) to learn more about options menu.

I don't see a point in adding the user name and password fields to an options menu. You could use a sub activity or a [dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) fragment to display those fields.

In your code, you have two problems.

> SubMenu sub = menu.addSubMenu(0,1,0, "Sign-In");
>     sub.add(0,11,0,edit_username);
>     sub.add(0,12,0,txtUsername);

1. you cannot nest submenus.
2. `add (int groupId, int itemId, int order, CharSequence title)` obviously takes CharSequence as parameter not the View widgets (your edittext and textview).

Comment: thanks very much this has made it a lot easier for me to understand than what I was searching for